# Compare result of query in one table and report "True" or "False"

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql which contains lots of data for some NE's. I want to create a report which compare value of a column and report as "True" or "False".

below table is part of my query, I want to fetch all data of T1 and T2 and compare value coulmn, it it is same, in new column put "True" otherwise" put "False".

```
+------------+----------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| date       | rnc      | mo              | parameterid                                                 | Value        |
+------------+----------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| 2018-07-11 | T1       | INTERRATHOCOV   | INTERRATCSTHD2DECN0                                         | -17          |
| 2018-07-11 | T2       | INTERRATHOCOV   | INTERRATCSTHD2FECN0                                         | -14          |
| 2018-07-11 | T1       | UMULTIRABHOCOV  | CSPSMRABTHD2DECN0                                           | -15          |
| 2018-07-11 | T2       | UMULTIRABHOCOV  | CSPSMRABTHD2FECN0                                           | -12          |
| 2018-07-17 | T1       | CORRMPARA       | PERFENHANCESWITCH9_PERFENH_NON_CS_RAB_RELOC_OPT_SW          | 0            |
| 2018-07-17 | T2       | CORRMPARA       | PERFENHANCESWITCH9_PERFENH_NON_PS_RAB_RELOC_OPT_SW          | 0            |
| 2018-07-19 | T4       | CORRMPARA       | PERFENHANCESWITCH9_PERFENH_NON_CS_RAB_RELOC_OPT_SW          | 0            |
| 2018-07-19 | T4       | CORRMPARA       | PERFENHANCESWITCH9_PERFENH_NON_PS_RAB_RELOC_OPT_SW          | 0            |
+------------+----------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: What is a NE? Compare value column but compare it to what?

Comment: the t1 and t2 rows are related  using mo or parameterid column ??

Comment: parameterid for one mo maybe more than 1, I want to comare something like this (T1-INTERRATHOCOV-INTERRATCSTHD2DECN0-Value) with (T2-INTERRATHOCOV-INTERRATCSTHD2DECN0-Value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried joining the table with itself ?

```
SELECT Table1.date, Table1.mo, Table1.parameterid, 
  IF(Table1.value = Table2.value, "True", "False") AS compare
FROM myTable AS Table1
LEFT JOIN myTable AS Table2 ON Table1.date = Table2.date AND Table1.mo = Table2.mo
  AND Table1.parameterid = Table2.parameterid AND Table1.rnc <> Table2.rnc
```

Comment: but there is issue with the speed, as it makes it very slow for a table of 3000, it take 5 minutes, is there any solution to make it faster ?

Comment: Yes - you can create indexes on the columns. However it would be better to convert your columns from VARCHAR to INTEGER and store your text values into a lookup table.